# How to download payload in NODE-RED?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am connecting to an oracle DB node and getting the payload through debug node.Is there a way to  download the payload in json format

Answer (score 1):

The `msg.payload` will already be a JSON object, what you see in the debug node is just a representation that's formatted for display in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can view the payload in debug mode but can you suggest me on how to download the same so that I can save it in my local.

Comment: There are a bunch of standard nodes that would allow that, update the question with what you have already tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, you have to try first then people will help you fix it.